# check if request is in the same request mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm developing an MVC app and I need to do a some business logic every time a request comes in, unless the request is a sub request, IE `@Html.Action("GetStuff", "Stuff")`. I'm setting the HttpContextUser with a custom user object.

```
if (SkipAuthorization(filterContext))
{
     return;
}
else
{
     filterContext.HttpContext.User = GetBusinessUser()
}
```

Where SkipAuthorization looks like this:

```
bool SkipAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
     //blah blah
     bool isInSameRequest = (filterContext.HttpContext.User != null
                       && filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity != null
                       && filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
    //more blah blah
    return result;
}
```

This has seemed to cause a bug when the server is set using winAuth, well I guess we all learn things huh?

My question is as follows, is there a better way to check to see if the request is a sub request and skip it or do I have to check to see if the User is type `WindowsIdentity`, or `MyCustomUser`? That throws a red flag in my mind about what other User types that I do not know about, and our business type could change.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a slightly different approach. Every action that is a child action ("sub request" as you call it) would be annotated with

```
[ChildActionOnly]
```

This prevents users from calling those actions directly.

Rendering child actions inside views does not trigger more requests, so you should be fine without any additional logic.

Comment: I'm not ok with this, because other developers will need to know to add this, I was hoping to solve it in the SkipAuthorization block of code.

Comment: This is a standard practice for asp.net mvc so other devs should know about it. But if you want a workardound, a good solution would be to check ViewData if it contains a certain key, eg: ViewData["firstrequest"]. You can do the authorization logic if the key is not present and set it, and all the other actions that run after that will see the key and skip the auth logic.